# WebRTC - How to change System Color to PAL?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm trying to use WebRTC to display a video input on-screen as a live feed to capture images. And i'm not trying to do any peer-to-peer communications.

My problem is my live captured-screen has pink color. So I'm trying to adjust the constraints for getUserMedia for `PAL` signal like so:

```
{
    "audio": false,
    "video": {
        "mandatory": {
            "maxWidth": 960,
            "maxHeight": 720,
            "maxAspectRatio": 1.333,
            "maxFrameRate": 30
        }
}
```

The above constraints i reference from: [WebRTC can't get a video feed from a USB input device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30203364/1896897)

But it does not help. If i use another software on my desktop, it will have pink color too. Then i change properties of this software to `PAL /BDGHI` then the screen is normal. See the image attached.

Additional information i was used:

Chrome version 51.26.2704.106 m

OS version: Windows 7 Ultimate (6.1.7601) SP1

Does anyone have any ideas what's causing this, and what is constraints i should pass to `getUserMedia` ?

Thank you very much !

The captured image is pink:

[image]

Other sofware configuration:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you have a hardware problem. Constraints have nothing to do with color. Also, the image you posted appears green to me. Lastly, I don't know what Properties page you're showing, but this site is for programming questions, not config problems.

Comment: The image is covered by pink. Surely, its not a hardware problem. Because the desktop application gives normal image if i change the properties. So, i do not know how to configure it with WebRTC

Comment: Still, it's a configuration problem specific to something you have installed. WebRTC and the web platform have no control surface for controlling S-Video to USB converters.

Comment: i guess it caused by the `NTSC /M` system color. So, i am trying to configure to change to `PAL /BDGHI` with some constraints of getUserMedia. It's new to me and i just guess, not sure about what i am doing :(